# Run ubuntu 16.04 bash shell in a docker image

Tags: docker

I have this Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
```

I run

```
docker build -t mine .
```

It builds. Then I run

```
docker exec -it mine /bin/bash
```

and it says

```
Error: No such container: mine
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but I've Googled for docker image name, I've run `docker images` and it shows the "CONTAINER ID" "mine" (with tag "latest"), I've looked at stackoverflow.  This is so basic it's hard to find the answer.

I'm running docker 19.03.2, build 6a30dfc, on OS X.

**EDIT**: If I run `docker run mine` it runs and immediately exits (of course, since that's what the Dockerfile says).  Then there's a container (not running).  Then if I exec that container by id, it says, "Container ..hex.. is not running," which makes sense.

I guess I want the simplest way to run a bash shell in Ubuntu 16.04.

Advice?

Comment: I always fo `docker run --rm -ti containername` possibly followed by a command, possibly with mount or port options etc pp.  Do `docker images` to see under what name your build succeeded.

Comment: For the edited question:  `docker run --rm -ti ubuntu:16.04` which will start `bash` by default.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Docker `exec` command is for executing a command inside of a **running** container. You simply need to `run` your container using `docker run -it mine /bin/bash`.

If your ultimate goal is to run Ubuntu's bash on itself, you can skip the `build` phase and just do `docker run -it ubuntu:16.04 /bin/bash`.

Notice the `-i` and `-t` flags. The first one indicates that your containerized program (i.e. bash) may receive some user input. Hence, docker will keep its stdin open. The second flag is to use a Linux pseudoterminal (PTY) as a controlling terminal of the command (i.e. bash). And the combination of these flags allows you to have a *normal* interactive shell experience.

Answer (score 2):

The reason behinde this `docker run mine` command is, It will run the container but it will be terminated because it will not allocate pseudo-tty

```
-t              : Allocate a pseudo-tty
-i              : Keep STDIN open even if not attached
```

> For interactive processes (like a shell), you must use -i -t together
>   in order to allocate a tty for the container process. -i -t is often
>   written -it as you’ll see in later examples. Specifying -t is
>   forbidden when the client is receiving its standard input from a pipe,
>   as in:

```
echo test | docker run -i busybox cat
```

so in your case you should allocate pseudo-tty for the ubuntu container.

```
docker run --name my_ubuntu_container -it ubuntu bash
```

Then you can run

```
--tty , -t      Allocate a pseudo-TTY
docker exec -it my_ubuntu_container bash
```

Answer (score 1):

that because you need to run it first before using `exec`

```
docker run -it mine bash
```

Comment: Yes. I changed the question to ask, "What's the simplest way to run an ubuntu 16.04 bash shell using docker?"

Comment: Oh, if I use -it (instead of -dti) for an interactive shell, this works. Thanks!